# Why am I getting a timeout error while trying to send TCP packets over the internet?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, timeoutexception, chatroom

I wanted to demonstrate Asynchronous Non-Blocking threads through an EventLoop using a chatroom that I coded out in Python.

The chatroom is working fine when I simulate a server and clients on my desktop, but whenever I want to send packets over the internet to my friends who stay at a geographically distant location, I receive Timeout errors.

Obviously, I change the `IP_ADDR` accordingly while doing so. In fact, I have tried both IPv4 and IPv6. The firewall is off, and there are no anti-viruses installed.

I tried setting the timeout options as well, but the problem still exists.

Over a small geographical distance, the connection works.

I have also checked whether I am even able to send packets over the Internet at all to the target computer using the `tracert` command, and it seems like I can.

**Server.py**

```
import sys
import select

import msvcrt
import socket

IP_ADDR = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5555
HEADER_SIZE = 10

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((IP_ADDR, PORT))

def add_header(username, msg):
    username = f'{len(username) :< {HEADER_SIZE}}' + username
    msg_len = len(msg)
    msg = username + f'{msg_len :< {HEADER_SIZE}}' + msg
    
    return msg.encode("utf-8")

sock_list = [server]
sock_dict = {server : 'Server'}

def broadcast_message(client, broadcast_msg):
    try: #EAFP
        client.send(broadcast_msg)
    except:
        username = sock_dict[client]
        del sock_dict[client]
        sock_list.remove(client)
        
        broadcast_msg = add_header(sock_dict[server], f"{username} has left the group!!")
        for clients in sock_list:
            if clients is server:
                print(f"{username} has left the group!!")
            else:
                broadcast_message(clients, broadcast_msg)

server.listen()
while True:
    readers, _, err_sockets = select.select(sock_list, [], [], 1)
    if(msvcrt.kbhit()):
        msg = input("[:] >> ")
        #msg = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
        msg = add_header(sock_dict[server], msg)
        
        for client in sock_list:
            if client is server:
                continue
            else:
                broadcast_message(client, msg)

    for reader in readers:
        if reader is server:
            client_socc, client_addr = server.accept()
            try:
                client_username = client_socc.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                if not len(client_username):
                    continue
                else:
                    print(f"Connection accepted from {client_username[HEADER_SIZE : ].title()} : {client_addr[0]} : {client_addr[1]}")
                    sock_dict[client_socc] = client_username[HEADER_SIZE : ].title()
                    sock_list.append(client_socc)
                    
                    broadcast_msg = add_header(sock_dict[server], f"{sock_dict[client_socc]} has joined the group!!")
                    for client in sock_list:
                        if client is server or client is client_socc:
                            continue
                        else:
                            broadcast_message(client, broadcast_msg)
            except:
                continue
        else:
            try:
                client_msg = reader.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                if not len(client_msg):
                    del sock_dict[reader]
                    sock_list.remove(reader)
                    
                else:
                    while len(client_msg):
                        broadcast_msg = add_header(sock_dict[reader], client_msg[HEADER_SIZE : HEADER_SIZE + int(client_msg[:HEADER_SIZE])])
                        print(f"{sock_dict[reader]} >> {client_msg[HEADER_SIZE : HEADER_SIZE + int(client_msg[:HEADER_SIZE])]}")
                        client_msg = client_msg[HEADER_SIZE + int(client_msg[:HEADER_SIZE]) : ]
                        
                        for client in sock_list:
                            if client is server or client is reader:
                                continue
                            else:
                                broadcast_message(client, broadcast_msg)
            except:
                continue
```

**Client.py**

```
import sys
import select

import socket
import msvcrt

IP_ADDR = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5555
HEADER_SIZE = 10

class Connection():
    def __init__(self, default = (IP_ADDR, PORT)):
        self.client_conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print(f"Trying to connect to {default[0]} : {default[1]}")
        self.client_conn.connect(default)
        
        print("Connection succesful!")
        username = input("Enter your username : ")
        username = f'{len(username) :< {HEADER_SIZE}}' + username
        self.client_conn.send(username.encode("utf-8"))
    
    def fileno(self):
        return self.client_conn.fileno()
    
    def on_read(self):
        msg = self.client_conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        self.decode_message(msg)
    
    def decode_message(self, msg):
        while len(msg):
            username = msg[HEADER_SIZE : HEADER_SIZE  + int(msg[: HEADER_SIZE])]
            msg = msg[HEADER_SIZE + int(msg[: HEADER_SIZE]) : ]
            
            user_msg = msg[HEADER_SIZE : HEADER_SIZE  + int(msg[: HEADER_SIZE])]
            msg = msg[HEADER_SIZE + int(msg[: HEADER_SIZE]) : ]
            
            print(f"{username} >> {user_msg}")

class Input():
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client.client_conn
    
    def fileno(self):
        return sys.stdin.fileno()
    
    def on_read(self):
        #msg = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
        msg = input("[:] >> ")
        msg_len = len(msg)
        msg = f'{msg_len :< {HEADER_SIZE}}' + msg
        
        self.client.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))
        
connection = Connection()
read_input = Input(connection)

while True:
    readers, _, _ = select.select([connection], [], [], 1)
    if(msvcrt.kbhit()):
        readers.append(read_input)
    for reader in readers:
        reader.on_read()
```

Comment: TTL? One key difference between running locally and a geographically distant place, is the number of hops. Is the TTL being set too low (no idea at all how this is usually set, btw)

Comment: *"I recieve the Timeout error."* - and exactly where? In client or in server? And at exactly which place of your code, i.e. connect, read, write? And is this really a timeout or do you interpret it only as a timeout? Is your server even publicly reachable at all, i.e. located at some system which has a public IP address or have some port forwarding from a public IP address?

Comment: So, I run the server script on my end and my friend, who's running the client script, gets the timeout error while CONNECTING. Yes, it's a timeout error. Yes, my server's reachable. He used the tracert command along with my ip on his system and he found out that my server was indeed reachable.

Comment: Moreover, I tried setting the default timeout limit to both a 100 seconds and 1000 seconds later but both of them throw the error after the same amount of time.

Comment: @TuhinMukherjee `tracert` will only tell you if an IP is reachable, not whether a TCP server at that IP is reachable.  If your server is running behind a NAT router, for instance (which is common for most home WiFi setups nowadays), the client needs to connect to the router's public IP assigned by the Internet modem, and then the router must have *port forwarding* configured to route incoming connections to the server machine.  This setup is not needed if the server machine is connected *directly* to the Internet modem.

Comment: @Remy, I don't have a modem currently. I have connected my laptop to my mobile hotspot. Sorry, still new to computer networking atm. What should I do now?

Comment: @TuhinMukherjee Then your mobile hotspot is acting as an Internet modem/router, and will have an IP assigned to it by the mobile carrier. But unless your mobile carrier allows you to run servers on their cellular network (not likely), then you will have no way for outside clients to reach your TCP server when it is running on the hotspot. You will have to talk to your carrier to verify that. Otherwise, you will have to switch roles - run your server on your friends Internet connection instead, and make your mobile laptop act as the client that connects to them.

Comment: @TuhinMukherjee you should direct any further non-programming networking questions to [sf].